# Unable to add Scroll view indide tabhost in android

Tags: android, xml

I am Unable to set Scroll view inside my android app development when i am adding scroll view it overlapping tab head and also unable to switch tabs thank you for your valuable time..`

```
    <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bRecharge">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/tabhost">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Mobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="419dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/DTH"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Datacard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>`
```

Comment: `TabHost` is deprecated use `TabLayout` from design support library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry friends .. its very simple to add scroll view in tabhost add scroll view the different activity xml files that we used in the main tabhost 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Open `<TabHost>` . In your code you're adding `</TabHost>` but I don't see anywhere the open of it.

Comment: I am sorry that tab host is there

Comment: <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

Comment: edit your post, then... Also, did you try to set all your framelayout inside the tabwidget?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JaiSoni please read my response... If you see, over the xml I don't see any open TabHost, so, that could be a solution. It wasn't to critique or request anything.